# Node.js and Socket.io array received in chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io

I have a problem with sending an array using socket.io. The client creates an array, populates it, and then sends it using socket.send(val), where val is the array. However, server-side, socket does not receive the array as an array, it receives the individual parts of the array as separate messages, so the entire array is not available in the 
client.on('message', function(only one element of the array){...});
Am I just an idiot doing something entirely wrong? I don'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first convert your data to JSON: `socket.send(JSON.stringify(val))`. Then on Node's end, it is trivial to get your original array: `var arr=JSON.parse(yourReceivedData);`